# Setup Crypto++ for Eclipse windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, eclipse-cdt, crypto++

I downloaded crypto++ 5.6.2 from [here](http://cryptopp.com/#download). I want to install it and start using it on Eclipse on windows. I am a new user of Eclipse and wanted to know steps to start using crypto++ in my project.

Comment: @giorgim As of now I only have the zip. How do I go from there ? The link says something about install.

Comment: Both mention installing before using. I am stuck at the installing part. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @jww I am using Eclipse CDT with Windows 8.1.